# The onClick event I have setup is not firing when I pressed the specified button

Tags: android

I have been working on an Android app for a project I'm a part of, and I've been having an issue with a button I've been searching up for a couple days now. The issue I've been having is that for some reason the onClick event is not firing for the button I have it setup.

Here is the Java:

```
    public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private Toast toast;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        final Button fuelPageButton;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fuelPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fuelButton);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        fuelPageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        toast.makeText(Dashboard.this ,"Button pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //setContentView(R.layout.fuel_saved);
    }
}
```

Here is the XML for the button:

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/fuelButton"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="-1dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to call `setContentView` before call `findViewById`:

```
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
        final Button fuelPageButton;
        fuelPageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fuelButton);  
        fuelPageButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

Comment: I tried this and the onClick method is still not firing.

Answer (score 1):

You made a toast, but you didn't put .show() behind it. It will not show then.

```
  toast.makeText(Dashboard.this ,"Button pressed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

And indeed setcontentview before findviewbyid...(See @Arthur Korchagin)